# android not fetch memory in multiple fragments

Tags: android, memory-leaks, picasso, universal-image-loader, android-glide

I'm developing android App. My app is showing many of pictures from server by image_url with ImageLoader Library such as Picasso, Glide or AUIL.

There are five fragments in main activity. and each of fragments have many image list view.

My question is that after I click specific image view, new activity is created, and then fragment is created that have many images list view. 
I clicked different images, and new activities are created. When this gesture occurred , heap memory is not fetched ...

Among of three libraries, AUIL is the best of them.

I tried recursing method at base adapter and drawable callback to null etc...

But This situation was not solved.

Here is my example Adapter sourse:

```
public class MagazineRelBrandItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<String> receivedList;
ArrayList<View> brandThumList = new ArrayList<>();
PrintLog printLog = new PrintLog(Application.isDEBUG(), "MagazineRelBrandItemAdap ", "created");
Activity mActivity;

public MagazineRelBrandItemAdapter(ArrayList<String> dataList, Activity activity) {
    receivedList = dataList;
    mActivity = activity;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return receivedList.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return receivedList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MagazineRelBrandView itemView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        itemView = new MagazineRelBrandView(Application.getContext(),mActivity);

    } else {
        itemView = (MagazineRelBrandView) convertView;

    }
    try {
        itemView.setContent(receivedList.get(position));
        brandThumList.add(itemView);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        if (mRecycleList.size() <= parent.getChildCount()) {
            printLog.cutsomPrintLog(Application.isDEBUG(), "img recycle size comment>>", mRecycleList.size() + "");
            throw e;
        }
        recycleHalf();
        System.gc();
        return getView(position, itemView, parent);
    }
    mRecycleList.add(new WeakReference<View>(itemView));
    return itemView;
}

private List<WeakReference<View>> mRecycleList = new ArrayList<WeakReference<View>>();

public void recycleHalf() {
    int halfSize = mRecycleList.size() / 2;
    List<WeakReference<View>> recycleHalfList = mRecycleList.subList(0, halfSize);
    RecycleUtils.recursiveRecycle(recycleHalfList);
    for (int i = 0; i < halfSize; i++)
        mRecycleList.remove(0);
}

public void recycle() {
    RecycleUtils.recursiveRecycle(mRecycleList);
}
}
```

And Here is my widget :

```
public class MagazineRelBrandView extends LinearLayout {
Activity mActivity;

public MagazineRelBrandView(Context context,Activity activity) {
    super(context);
    mActivity = activity;
    init();
}

CircleImageView brandLogo;
TextView brandName;
ImageView brandBg;
View clickV;

private void init() {

    inflate(getContext(), R.layout.magazine_rel_brand_view, this);
    brandBg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.magazine_rel_brand_bg);
    brandName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.magazine_rel_brand_name);
    brandLogo = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.magazine_rel_brand_icon);
    clickV = findViewById(R.id.content_click_view);
    brandName.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), CommonKeys.FuturaFont));
    clickV.setOnClickListener(goBrandDetailPageListener);
}


public void setContent(String brandName) {
    this.brandName.setText(brandName);
    try {
        String brandTitleUrl;
        brandTitleUrl = URLEncoder.encode(brandName, "UTF-8");
        totalThumbUrl = CommonKeys.brandThumbUrl + brandTitleUrl;
        totalBackUrl = CommonKeys.brandBackgroundUrl + brandTitleUrl;

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    showBG(brandName);
    showLogo(brandName);
}
String totalThumbUrl;
String totalBackUrl;

public void showLogo(final String brandName){
    Glide.with(mActivity).load(totalThumbUrl).override(DpToPxUtil.dp2px(38),DpToPxUtil.dp2px(38)).into(brandLogo);

}public void showBG(final String brandName){
    Glide.with(mActivity).load(totalBackUrl).override(DpToPxUtil.dp2px(120),DpToPxUtil.dp2px(144)).into(brandBg);
}

public String getBrandName() {
    return brandName.getText().toString();
}

Handler brandHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case 0:
                MyToast.show("" + msg.obj);
                break;
            case 1:

                BrandInfoZip brandInfoZip = (BrandInfoZip) ((BrandInfoParentZip) msg.obj).getData();

                BrandListZip getBrandZip = new BrandListZip();
                getBrandZip.setIs_following(brandInfoZip.is_following());
                getBrandZip.setBrand_name(getBrandName());

                Intent goBrandPage = new Intent(Application.getContext(), BrandDetailActivity.class);
                goBrandPage.putExtra("brandZip", getBrandZip);
                goBrandPage.putExtra("title", getBrandName());
                goBrandPage.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                Application.getContext().startActivity(goBrandPage);
                break;
        }
    }
};

OnClickListener goBrandDetailPageListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        BrandDescriptionZip brandDescriptionZip = new BrandDescriptionZip();
        brandDescriptionZip.setBrand_name(getBrandName());
        new GetBrandInfoFromServer(brandHandler).execute(brandDescriptionZip);

    }
};
}
```

And fragment onDestroyView sourse :

```
 @Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (upperBgImgV.getDrawable() != null) {
        upperBgImgV.getDrawable().setCallback(null);
    }
    if (writerThumb.getDrawable() != null) {
        writerThumb.getDrawable().setCallback(null);
    }
    if (otherContentV.getDrawable() != null) {
        otherContentV.getDrawable().setCallback(null);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    Glide.clear(writerThumb);
    magazineRelBrandItemAdapter.recycle();
    unbindDrawables(getView());
    //unbindDrawables(writerThumb);
    //unbindDrawables(otherContentV);
    System.gc();
    super.onDestroyView();
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroyView-");
}
private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
    if (view == null)
        return;

    if (view instanceof ImageView) {
        ((ImageView) view).setImageDrawable(null);
    }
    if (view.getBackground() != null) {
        view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
    }
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
            unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
        }
        view.setBackgroundResource(0);
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    }
}
```

and Here is activity onDestroy() course :

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    RecycleUtils.recursiveRecycle(getWindow().getDecorView());
    System.gc();
    Glide.get(this).clearMemory();
    FlurryAgent.onEndSession(Application.getContext());
    printLog.cutsomPrintLog(Application.isDEBUG(),"Magazine Detail Activity onDestroy-","onDestroy-");
    super.onDestroy();
    finish();
}
```

These course is used to clear memory heap. But Memory leak is continue....

Please help me.